# Run setup before make target and "finally" afterwards?

Tags: makefile

I'm working on a project that uses many imported Makefiles that I do not control. I only control the single Makefile at the root of the repo. A target in one of the other Makefiles runs tests on the code I'm working on. However, there is an additional setup and teardown requirement for my code.

I can add a target to my local Makefile as a dependency of the common target. This allows for the setup to run. However, I also need to tear down after the fact. The tear down needs to happen ***always***, even if the make target failed. Example code below:

```
.PHONY: common/test local/setup local/teardown

# This includes the setup as needed
common/test: local/setup

local/setup:
        # Alter files to allow destruction of test resources

# But how do I ensure this runs? Depending on the user to run it is error prone...
# Also, this step needs to run EVEN IF the common/test target failed
local/teardown:
        # Revert files so they don't get committed to source control
        # because we need resource destruction disallowed in production
```

Comment: By "even if the target fails" do you include failure scenarios such as someone hitting ^C or sending a SIGINT?  Or are you only worried about if the `common/test` recipe failed in the normal way (exited with a non-0 exit code)?

Comment: Good question, I'm primarily focused on the failure of the common/test recipe. If a user interrupts a make, they can expect to clean up the partial state.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such thing as teardown facility in make unfortunately.  The best you can do is put it into the same recipe, but capture the exit code on failure so it still runs.

For example say that the recipe for `common/test` was something like:

```
common/test: local/setup
        run my test
```

Then you'd have to use:

```
common/test: local/setup
        run my test; ret=$$?; \
        perform teardown operations; \
        exit $$ret
```

Comment: This will work. I'll actually be writing a "local/test" target whose recipe does both setup and teardown, with the call to common/test in the middle. Capturing the return code is the missing piece to ensure the teardown steps run.